# Average for Yearly data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is my code, I know the join is not proper. The query below is giving me values for 12 months for the year 1985 but I want to find the average for this particular and I have no idea how

```
WITH samplefordata AS 
(
    SELECT
        ersbusinesslogic_id,
        ersbusinesslogic_inputdataseries
    FROM 
        cosd.ersbusinesslogic
    WHERE 
        ersbusinesslogic_formula LIKE '%Avg%'
        AND ersbusinesslogic_inputtimedimensionvalue = 'all months'
)
SELECT
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_id,
    AVG(cosd.ersdatavalues.ersdatavalues_attributevalue) AS outputvalue,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputdestination,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_longdesc,
    GETDATE(),
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputunitid,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_privacyid,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_inputsources,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_inputsourceid,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputtimedimensionvalue,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputtimedimensiontypeid,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputname,
    Concat(cosd.erstimedimension_lu.erstimedimension_year, '-' + '01' + '-' + '01'),
    4 AS [ERSConstructedVariable_DataRowLifecyclePhaseID],
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_outputgeographydimensionid,
    cosd.erstimedimension_lu.erstimedimension_id
FROM 
    cosd.ersdatavalues,
    cosd.erstimedimension_lu,
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic,
    cosd.ersgeographydimension_lu
WHERE 
    cosd.ersdatavalues.ersdatavalues_erstimedimension_id = cosd.erstimedimension_lu.erstimedimension_id
    AND cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_inputgeographydimensionid = cosd.ersgeographydimension_lu.ersgeographydimension_id
    AND cosd.ersdatavalues.ersdatavalues_erscommodity_id = 132--      samplefordata.ersbusinesslogic_inputdataseries
    AND cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_id =499--      samplefordata.ersbusinesslogic_id
    AND cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_inputtimedimensionvalue = 'all months'
    AND cosd.erstimedimension_lu.erstimedimension_timedimensiontype_id = 11
    AND cosd.ERSTimeDimension_LU.ERSTimeDimension_Year=1985
    AND cosd.ersdatavalues.ersdatavalues_ersunit_id = cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_inputunitid
GROUP BY 
    cosd.ersbusinesslogic.ersbusinesslogic_id,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputdestination,
    ersbusinesslogic_longdesc,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputunitid,
    ersbusinesslogic_inputsources,
    ersbusinesslogic_inputsourceid,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputtimedimensionvalue,
    ersbusinesslogic_privacyid,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputtimedimensiontypeid,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputname,
    ersbusinesslogic_outputgeographydimensionid,
    erstimedimension_year,
    erstimedimension_id
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please add to this an [mcve] - some input data, some expected output and some actual output will help a lot. Bonus points for a SQL Fiddle or similar.

Comment: Please add to this an [mcve] - some input data, some expected output and some actual output will help a lot. Bonus points for a SQL Fiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Also `GROUP BY cosd.erstimedimension_lu.erstimedimension_year`

Comment: @user3715927 No, it's not. Copy your query to an editor and use a find command to search for `erstimedimension_year`. It is only contained in a calculated column, but not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: in the group by, I have added in the second last line.

Comment: Great. So now, after changing nothing, everything should work just fine. If not, add an error message or whatever the problem is.

Comment: I am getting 12 values for 12 months in a year. I just want to have one value per year. Sorry if i was not clear before

Comment: @user3715927  Well, then you will have to remove at least one grouping field and corresponding column from the select list that break up a year into months. Since I am not very well in clearvoyance, from just reading the field names, I can't say which one(s) should come into consideration.